# How to block domain access?

Tags: htaccess

I'm studying AWStats in my server and I see no interesting domain access. How can I block it with [htaccess](http://www.develop-site.com/blog/92) or another solution

Comment: could you give some code like whats your current domain? From whom do you want to block it from? because simply blocking may even block you from using it.

Comment: Add clarity to your question by adding some details.

Comment: Not programming related in any way.

Comment: Unfortunately your question doesn't make any sense in its current form. If you can clarify exactly what you are looking for please edit your question and then flag it to let the moderators know it has been improved. Then we can reopen it for you.